# Solo me carga el operacion suma en Calculadora html y js

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, clase, javascript-objeto

Os adjunto primero mi codigo .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Calculadora 0</title>
    <script src="Calculadora.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="display">0</p>
    <button type="button" id="boton1" value="1" class="digito">1</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton2" value="2" class="digito">2</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton3" value="3" class="digito">3</button>
    <button type="button" id="suma" value="+" class="operador">+</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="boton4" value="4" class="digito">4</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton5" value="5" class="digito">5</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton6" value="6" class="digito">6</button>
    <button type="button" id="resta" value="-" class="operador">-</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="boton7" value="7" class="digito">7</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton8" value="8" class="digito">8</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton9" value="9" class="digito">9</button>
    <button type="button" id="mult" value="*" class="operador">x</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="boton0" value="0." class="digito">0.</button>
    <button type="button" id="boton00" value="00" class="digito">00</button>
    <button type="button" id="clear">AC</button>
    <button type="button" id="div" value="/" class="operador">/</button>
    <button type="button" id="igual">=</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y ahora el programa en .js que se ejecuta y donde me encuentro con el fallo en el bucle de los operadores.

En este bucle es donde quiero obtener el valor del boton 'operador' al presionarse en html

operador es una función  que tiene la siguiente forma y donde se tiene en cuenta que la calculadora funciona como una maquina de estados.

```
function operador (op){
  //-- Segun el estado hacemos una cosa u otra
  if (estado == ESTADO.OP1){
    display.innerHTML += op;
    estado = ESTADO.OPERATION;
  }else if(estado == ESTADO.OP2_INIT){
    display.innerHTML += op;
    estado = ESTADO.OP2;
  }else if (estado == ESTADO.OP2){
    display.innerHTML += op;
    estado = ESTADO.OP2;
  }
}

op = document.getElementsByClassName("operador")
//-- Insertar simbolo de operador
for (i=0; i<operador.length; i++) {
  op[i].onclick = (ev) => {
    operador(ev.target.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código faltante, te falta la variable operador no?

Comment: añado parte de codigo que falta

Comment: creo que en bucle debería ser `op.length` ya que la variable `op` es la que tiene los elementos. Y `operador` es la funcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable que tiene todos los operadores es `op` y no `operador`. Por esto, solo se hace una iteración del bucle y se asigna el `click` al primer elemento del array `op`. En tu caso es suma.

```
op = document.getElementsByClassName("operador")
//-- Insertar simbolo de operador
for (i=0; i<op.length; i++) {
  op[i].onclick = (ev) => {
    operador(ev.target.value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Ese era el error.

Un saludo!